# How to migrate from SQLite to PostgreSQL (Rails)

Tags: ruby-on-rails, sqlite, postgresql, heroku, database-migration

I'm a DB noob so please be kind with me.

I'm having some issues pushing my SQLite DB to Heroku via taps gem. Talking with them, they told me one of the solutions could be converting locally my DB from SQLite to PostgreSQL.
Is there an easy way to do so?

Thanks

More info:
- DB from Rails app
- I'm on Mac OS X
- Just installed PostgreSQL via macports

Comment: Now there's a better way - use the taps gem as described in http://railscasts.com/episodes/342-migrating-to-postgresql

Answer (score 20, accepted):

`sqlite3 development.db .dump | psql dbname username`

Comment: note that some datatypes need to be converted ,http://stackoverflow.com/a/4581921/1099531

Comment: To connect to a psql database: 
`psql -h <host> -p <port> -U <username> <database>` You will be prompted for a password.

Answer (score 8):

[Sequel](http://sequel.jeremyevans.net) will help you

```
gem install sequel

sequel -C sqlite://db/development.sqlite3 postgres://username:password@localhost/dbname
```

Comment: Was Very helpful