# Migrating from sqlite3 to postgresql on Rails 3?

Tags: database, ruby-on-rails-3, sqlite, postgresql

Following the post: [How to migrate from SQLite to PostgreSQL (Rails)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4248072/how-to-migrate-from-sqlite-to-postgresql-rails)

I am running `sqlite3 development.sqlite3 .dump | psql mypgdb mypguser` in my Rails app and I'm getting this error (same for all models/tables in my app):

```
ERROR:  current transaction is aborted, commands ignored until end of transaction block
ERROR:  current transaction is aborted, commands ignored until end of transaction block
ERROR:  current transaction is aborted, commands ignored until end of transaction block
ERROR:  current transaction is aborted, commands ignored until end of transaction block
ERROR:  current transaction is aborted, commands ignored until end of transaction block
ERROR:  current transaction is aborted, commands ignored until end of transaction block
ERROR:  current transaction is aborted, commands ignored until end of transaction block
ERROR:  current transaction is aborted, commands ignored until end of transaction block
ERROR:  current transaction is aborted, commands ignored until end of transaction block
ERROR:  current transaction is aborted, commands ignored until end of transaction block
ERROR:  current transaction is aborted, commands ignored until end of transaction block
ERROR:  syntax error at or near "AUTOINCREMENT"
LINE 1: ...E TABLE "projects" ("id" INTEGER PRIMARY KEY AUTOINCREM...
```

Would appreciate some suggestions/fixed. Thanks!

Answer (score 2):

That's not valid SQL for PostgreSQL - you probably want a [SERIAL](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.2/static/datatype-numeric.html#DATATYPE-SERIAL) instead of INTEGER AUTOINCREMENT. You may want to [manually set the nextval](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.2/static/functions-sequence.html) of thesequence to max(id)+1 too.

Then you'll want to deal with all the other differences between a mostly-typeless sqlite and a strict PostgreSQL.

Then you'll want to stop using different systems on your development setup and in deployment. It's just causing yourself pain.

Answer (score 0):

I recommand you to use `gem "yaml_db"`, it's purpose is to move tables from one database to another.
https://github.com/ludicast/yaml_db#readme

You can get everything done simply by this gem with a nice documentation. It has 2 basic commands so nothing difficult about it.